# What's the Pythonic way to append to a bytearray a list?

Tags: python, arrays, format

I'm trying to append the contents of a list (which only contains hex numbers) to a bytearray. Right now I'm doing this and it works:

```
payload = serial_packets.get()
final_payload = bytearray(b"StrC")
final_payload.append(len(payload))
for b in payload:
   final_payload.append(b)
```

However, I believe it's not very Pythonic. Is there a better way to do this?

tldr; How can I append payload to final_payload in a more Pythonic way?

Comment: I don't think "Pythonian" is very Pythonic.

Comment: why are you appending len(payload)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can [extend](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), you don't need to iterate over payload:

```
final_payload.extend(payload)
```

Not sure  you want `final_payload.append(len(payload))` either.